# How to install Gulp in PhpStorm in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: gulp

I need install Gulp in PhpStorm.

My OS: ubuntu 16.04.
My PhpStorm: 2016.3.3.

How to install Gulp in PhpStorm?

I need work with gulpfile.js

**Edit 1:**

After run this command, show this error:

`sudo apt-get install nodejs`

Show error:
`E: Some packages could not be authenticated`

**Edit 2:**

After run `sudo apt-get update` show this error:

```
W: GPG error: https://deb.nodesource.com/node_7.x xenial InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 1655A0AB68576280
W: The repository 'https://deb.nodesource.com/node_7.x xenial InRelease' is not signed.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/node.js/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/node.js/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you must install [node](https://nodejs.org/en/) and [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/). Using Linux you could use

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nodejs
sudo apt-get install npm
```

After doing that, you could use next command to install gulp:

```
npm init
npm install gulp-cli -g
npm install gulp --save-dev
```

This are respectively:

1. Set up a new npm project
2. Install the `gulp` commands and must stand global on your computer
3. Install gulp to access the gulp files and add it to the `package.json` file as a development tool

And it's done.

The advantage of JavaScript is that you need the source code to run extern packages or libraries. You can combine everything even with an ASP.NET application to transpile SaSS or SCSS.

Comment: @Ali Try maby first `sudo apt-get update` and do it again? Found here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/75565/why-am-i-getting-authentication-errors-for-packages-from-an-ubuntu-repository